# Knockoutjs ObservableArray

Tags: knockout.js, ko.observablearray

The following snippet -- results in an empty list-box. Could anyone tell me what am doing wrong?

```
<script src="/Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.debug.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var listEditorVM = function () {
    this.allItems = ko.observableArray(["Apple", "Banana", "Orange"]);
    alert(this.allItems().length);
};
ko.applyBindings(new listEditorVM());

</script>

<div>List items:</div>
<select multiple="multiple" data-bind="options: allItems"></select>
```

Works is jsFiddle -- not in the browser(s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `ko.applyBindings` after your DOM is ready.  You could do this by moving that script block to the bottom of the page or call it in something like jQuery's [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function.

By default, jsFiddle will run your js code "onload", so it will happen after your elements are there.